# grep command fails on one Windows PC, but works on other Windows PC w/ same configuration

Tags: windows, command-line, shell, adb

I want to issue a **logcat** command to filter logs specifying a keyword (say apk). But I am facing an issue where the **grep** command is not recognized on one of my windows 7 PC. The same command works perfectly on other PC with same configuration.

Command issued on windows command prompt :

```
adb logcat | grep apk
```

Output :

```
'grep' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.
```

Output of working setup :

```
01-01 00:00:41.212  1598  2192 W PackageParser: No actions in intent filter at /system/priv-app/GoogleRestore/GoogleRestore.apk Binary XML file line #94
01-01 00:00:41.228  1598  2193 W PackageParser: No actions in intent filter at /system/priv-app/Contacts/Contacts.apk Binary XML file line #443
```

Need help in knowing the delta between two PCs. And how can I get the same command working on other PC as well.

Comment: Either one of them has `grep` installed and the other doesn't, or one has `grep` in the default `PATH` and the other doesn't.

Comment: Would you please be so kind as to run PATH on both machine HAPPY and machine SAD, and to post the results above by clicking on the `edit` link above and to the left? And, please also do `C: && CD \ && dir /s grep.exe` {Enter} on each PC and post the results by the same means.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using **grep**, may I suggest the native windows command [find](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html) would work as well in this example?

```
adb logcat | FIND /I "apk"
```